# More efficient way to compute angles?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataframe with three points given as columns (so, a total of six):

```
x_measured  y_measured  x_calculated  y_calculated  x_fixedpoint  \
0         142          37           143          37.5           138   
1         142          37           143          37.6           138   
2         142          37           143          37.7           138   
3         142          37           143          37.8           138   
4         142          37           143          37.9           138   
5          73          55            71          55.6            72   
6          73          55            71          55.7            72   
7          73          55            71          55.8            72   
8          73          55            71          55.9            72   
9          73          55            71          55.1            72   

   y_fixedpoint  
0            38  
1            38  
2            38  
3            38  
4            38  
5            55  
6            55  
7            55  
8            55  
9            55
```

Now, I need to calculate the angle between `(x_measured,  y_measured)` and `(x_calculated  y_calculated)` relative to `(x_fixedpoint, y_fixedpoint)`. To do so, I created this function:

```
def angle_calculator(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6):
    All_points = np.array([[x1,x2],[x3,x4],[x5,x6]])
    A = All_points[2] - All_points[0]
    B = All_points[1] - All_points[0]
    C = All_points[2] - All_points[1]

    for e1, e2 in ((A, B), (A, C), (B, -C)):
        dotproduct = np.dot(e1, e2)
        norm = np.linalg.norm(e1) * np.linalg.norm(e2)
        if dotproduct !=0:
            angle = round(np.arccos(dotproduct/norm) * 180 / np.pi, 2)
        else:
            angle = 0
    return angle
```

taking the different x,y coordinates as arguments and returning an angle. It works and gives:

```
df['angles'] = df.apply(lambda x: angle_calculator(x.x_measured, x.y_measured, x.x_calculated, x.y_calculated, x.x_fixedpoint, x.y_fixedpoint), axis=1)

x_measured  y_measured  x_calculated  y_calculated  x_fixedpoint  \
0         142          37           143          37.5           138   
1         142          37           143          37.6           138   
2         142          37           143          37.7           138   
3         142          37           143          37.8           138   
4         142          37           143          37.9           138   
5          73          55            71          55.6            72   
6          73          55            71          55.7            72   
7          73          55            71          55.8            72   
8          73          55            71          55.9            72   
9          73          55            71          55.1            72   

   y_fixedpoint     angles  
0            38  32.275644  
1            38  35.537678  
2            38  38.425651  
3            38  40.950418  
4            38  43.132975  
5            55  14.264512  
6            55  15.701974  
7            55  16.858399  
8            55  17.759467  
9            55   2.848188
```

Usually, I would be realatively pleased with this BUT.....it is rather slow for dataframes with over 200 000 rows. Slow (Iknow!) is a realtive term, but in this cas it takes around 10 seconds for 200 000 rows.

So, my questions are:

1. Am I overcomplicating things?
2. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

As always, thankful for knowledge.

Comment: Your function looks at `(A, B), (A, C), (B, -C)` pairs but since `angle` is overridden in each turn, only `(B, -C)` is in effect. But instead, shouldn't you be looking at `(A, C)` pair only? What I understood from the *relative* angle is the angle between `fixed - measured` and `fixed - calculated`, hence the `(A, C)` pair. Can you please clarify on this?

Comment: Yes! You are entirely right. Will change that and check if it is any faster. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I understood, I tried to write an answer but not sure the end result matches your required output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the values in the numpy domain, we can do:

```
# extract the pairs (and go to numpy)
meas = df.filter(like="measured").to_numpy()
calc = df.filter(like="calculated").to_numpy()
fix = df.filter(like="fixed").to_numpy()

# calculate the differences of `meas` and `calc` from `fix`
meas_dist = fix - meas
calc_dist = fix - calc

# get the inner products
inners = (meas_dist * calc_dist).sum(axis=1)
# or with: inners = np.einsum("ij,ij->i", meas_dist, calc_dist); might be faster

# norm function for brevity
norm = lambda mat: np.linalg.norm(mat, axis=1)

# get the angles (in radians)
angles_in_rad = np.arccos(inners / (norm(meas_dist) * norm(calc_dist)))

# handling possible NaNs (by @Serge de Gosson de Varennes, thanks!)
where_nans = isnan(angles_in_rad)
angles_in_rad[where_nans ] = 0

# go to degrees
angles_in_deg = np.rad2deg(angles_in_rad)

# put back to df
df["angles"] = angles_in_deg
```

I get:

```
>>> df

   x_measured  y_measured  x_calculated  y_calculated  x_fixedpoint  y_fixed_point      angles
0         142          37           143          37.5           138             38    8.325650
1         142          37           143          37.6           138             38    9.462322
2         142          37           143          37.7           138             38   10.602613
3         142          37           143          37.8           138             38   11.745633
4         142          37           143          37.9           138             38   12.890481
5          73          55            71          55.6            72             55  149.036243
6          73          55            71          55.7            72             55  145.007980
7          73          55            71          55.8            72             55  141.340192
8          73          55            71          55.9            72             55  138.012788
9          73          55            71          55.1            72             55  174.289407
```

Comment: Great work! Much faster! If I can come with one suggestion, it would be the following. It is not always certain that the norm (or products of norms are non.zero). So, it could very well result in ```nan``` values. I suggest the addition of ```angles_in_rad = np.arccos(inners/(norm(meas_dist) * norm(calc_dist)))
where_nans = isnan(angles_in_rad)
angles_in_rad[where_nans ] = 0```.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes oh, that's my poor math skills, thank you for the correction!